# Maven: Interleave multiple executions of a plugin with other plugin executions in a single phase

Tags: maven

I need to do the following in the pre-integration-test phase:

1. sql-maven-plugin:execute
2. jetty-maven-plugin:deploy-war
3. sql-maven-plugin:execute

Steps 1 and 3 have different configurations. I tried defining 1 and 3 as separate plugin elements, but I believe Maven just merges them into one plugin definition, resulting in an execution order of 1, 3, 2.

I need some way to execute these in the order defined above.

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to do this. Can you not move step 3 into the integration-test phase?

Comment: In step 2, the application runs database migrations. Only after this can I run 3, which loads test data to the database.

Comment: So, have you tried moving the second sql plug-in into the integration-test phase? If it's the first plugin declared that's bound to that phase it'll be the first one to run. That should fix your problem.

Comment: I'd considered this, but wanted to search for a better way that doesn't obscure the intention/integrity. Please add this as your answer so you can get some credit.

Answer (score 0):

Short notice about maven build process:

1. You can describe each plugin only once in pom.xml, duplicate descriptions is a bad practice (error prone).
2. You can describe multiple separate executions for each plugin.
3. Executions of the single plugin (bound to the single phase) will run in a sequence, regardless of other plugin definitions.
4. Executions of the different plugins (bound to the single phase) will run in a sequence as they are described in pom.xml.

Thinking about this statements you have **a simple way** - bind (1) and (3) to different phases.

I suggest you to bind

- (1) and (2) to 'pre-integration-test' phase, and
- (3) to 'integration-test' phase

It will solve the sequence problem. See also full list of phases in [maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) to find proper phases for your case.

And you have **an alternative way**, if you run this scenario only from CI server. You can configure build job for explicit multiple-steps build via separate profiles in pom.xml:

- build binaries
- migrate scheme
- deploy app
- load test data

It is much more complex and error prone, so I prefer the first way.