# Maven: run plugin twice during a phase, interleaved with another plugin

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, liquibase, sql-maven-plugin

For our end-2-end test we need to execute the following logical flow:

1. Create and set up e2e schema (user) in the database (`pre-integration-test`)
2. Run Liquibase to initially populate the schema (`pre-integration-test`)
3. Add e2e-specific test data to the DB tables (`pre-integration-test`)
4. Start Tomcat (`pre-integration-test`)
5. Run the web application in Tomcat (`integration-test`) using Protractor
6. Shut down Tomcat (`post-integration-test`)
7. Clean up the DB: drop the schema (`post-integration-test`)

For running SQL the `sql-maven-plugin` is used, however this flow doesn't fit the regular POM layout:

- The SQL plugin has to run during `pre-integration-test` twice, **before** and **after** the `liquibase-maven-plugin`
- The SQL plugin has to run **before** Tomcat plugin during `pre-integration-test`, however it has to run **after** during `post-integration-test`, so that the DB schema is dropped after Tomcat has shut down.

As far as I could conclude from [Maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-default-execution-ids.html), the order of plugins in the POM defines the order of execution during the same phase, and a plugin cannot be mentioned twice in the same POM.

**Question**: Is there any way to achieve this, apart from writing a shell script that would invoke Maven multiple times?

P.S. found a similar [unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137505/maven-interleave-multiple-executions-of-a-plugin-with-other-plugin-executions-i).

Comment: As workaround I suggest to use exec-maven-plugin from Step 3 downward as maven cli

Comment: Not possible, even declaring the same plugin twice in the pom (with the order you wanted, interleaved by another plugin) will result in a merge of its executions and as such the final order would not be impacted (executing first the goals for the same phase of the first declared plugin, then the interleaved one). Listing all of these goals from cli or via exec maven plugin is indeed a solution, but not optional (they would run outside of a phase). A feature request would probably be a better idea.

Comment: Yes that's what I observed too, mentioning a plugin twice indeed results in a somewhat unexpected behaviour. I think writing an external control script will be the best solution really, although it's platform-dependent.

Answer (score 4):

Given the sample POM below:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>print-hello</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <echo message="hello there!" />
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>exec-echo</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>cmd</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>/C</argument>
                                <argument>echo</argument>
                                <argument>hello-from-exec</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>print-hello-2</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <echo message="hello there 2!" />
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

We are actually configuring:

- The `maven-antrun-plugin` to print the `hello there!` message
- The `exec-maven-plugin` to print the `hello-from-exec` message
- The `maven-antrun-plugin` to print the `hello there 2!` message

Goal executions are all attached to the same phase, `validate`, and we would expect to be executed in the same defined order.

However, when invoking (the `-q` option is used to have exactly and only their output):

```
mvn validate -q
```

we would have as output:

```
main:
     [echo] hello there!

main:
     [echo] hello there 2!
hello-from-exec
```

That is, for the same phase, Maven executed the defined plugins, however merging all of the defined executions for the same plugins (even if defined as different `plugin` sections) and then execute them in the order to merged definitions.

Unfortunately, there is no mechanism to avoid this *merging*. The only options we have for configuring plugins execution behaviors are:

- The [`inherited`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins) configuration entry:

  > `true` or `false`, whether or not this plugin configuration should apply to POMs which inherit from this one. Default value is `true`.
- The `combine.children` and `combine.self` to

  > control how child POMs inherit configuration from parent POMs by adding attributes to the children of the configuration element.

None of these options would help us. In this case we would need a kind of `merge` attribute on the `execution` element or have a different behavior by default (that is, Maven should respect the definition order).

---

Invoking the single executions from command line as below:

```
mvn antrun:run@print-hello exec:exec@exec-echo antrun:run@print-hello-2 -q
```

We would instead have the desired output:

```
main:
     [echo] hello there!
hello-from-exec

main:
     [echo] hello there 2!
```

But in this case:

- We are not attached to any phase
- We are invoking directly specific executions (and their configurations) via command line (and via a new [feature](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5768) only available since Maven **3.3.1**

You can achieve exactly the same via scripting or via exec-maven-plugin invoking maven itself, but - again - the same would apply: no phase applied, only sequence of executions.

Comment: @yktoo did you solve this issue eventually? you didn't accept the answer nor share additional feedbacks. just checking :)

Comment: I'm interested as well :)

Comment: This is working when using the `plugins` in the top-level `build`-tag. But if one uses `profiles` it does not work anymore, for whatever reason. I had to add a separate `profile` to do the second execution of the plugin.