# Order of maven plug-in execution

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-failsafe-plugin

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243912/changing-the-order-of-maven-plugin-execution) it is stated:

> since Maven 3.0.3, for two plugins bound to the same phase, the order
>   of execution is the same as the order in which you *define* them

I'm using Maven **3.3.9** and I can see that execution order is NOT ALWAYS defined by order of plugins in the POM.

I have the following plugins bound to Maven lifecycle phases:

```
pre-integration-test:  maven-resources-plugin, 3.0.1            - prepares certain files
integration-test:      maven-failsafe-plugin, 2.19.1            - runs Cucumber-jvm tests
post-integration-test: exec-maven-plugin (id: cleaner), 1.5.0   - stops certain processes
                       maven-cucumber-reporting, 2.4.0          - generates rich HTML report
                       exec-maven-plugin (id: converter), 1.5.0 - converts rich HTML report to a light version
```

The three plugins bound to the "post-integration-test" phase are listed here in the order they are *defined* in the POM.
If all tests pass without errors (at the "integration-test" phase) - these plugins are executed as expected: in the order they are defined in the POM.
But **if any of the tests fail** - then I get the following situation:

- 3rd plugin is run first - "exec-maven-plugin (id: converter)". It
  doesn't find the "rich HTML report" to convert and fails.
- After that the 2nd plugin runs - "maven-cucumber-reporting". It successfully
  generates the "rich HTML report".
- And the 1st plugin - "exec-maven-plugin (id: cleaner)" - **never gets run**.

One strange thing more: although "maven-cucumber-reporting" plugin generates rich HTML report successfully, I see the following in the log file: *"Failed to execute goal maven-cucumber-reporting:2.4.0:generate (execution) on project ...: Error Found: BUILD FAILED"*.

If I comment out 2nd and 3rd plugins in the POM - then the remaining plugin ("exec-maven-plugin (id: cleaner)") runs **successfully**. In this case I see the following in the log file: *"Failed to execute goal maven-failsafe-plugin:2.19.1:verify (default) on project ...: There are test failures"*. Well, this message is quite expected.

**QUESTION:** Why plugins bound to the same phase are not executed in the order they are defined in the POM (**but** only when previous phase has failed)?

Comment: can you share the releavent `pom.xml` part?

Comment: This is potentially related to [this SO q/a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37434109/maven-run-plugin-twice-during-a-phase-interleaved-with-another-plugin). About "these plugins are executed as expected", are you sure about that?

Comment: This part is about 6000 symbols - too long for this comment. And attachments are not allowed here.

Yes, when all tests pass without errors - these plugins are executed as expected: in the order they are defined in the POM.

Comment: please add the relevant parts of your `pom.xml` to the **question** (via `edit`) , not in a comment

Comment: I read the link. They say we cannot define same plugin twice in the same POM. So I changed binding:

    pre-integration-test:  maven-resources-plugin, 3.0.1            - prepares certain files
    integration-test:      maven-failsafe-plugin, 2.19.1            - runs Cucumber-jvm tests
    post-integration-test: exec-maven-plugin (id: cleaner), 1.5.0   - stops certain processes
                           maven-cucumber-reporting, 2.4.0          - generates rich HTML report
    verify:                exec-maven-plugin (id: converter), 1.5.0 - converts rich HTML report to a light version

Comment: Now there is only ONE definition of the exec-maven-plugin, but it has TWO executions bound to different phases. Well, I got another problem now: the 2nd execution (bound to the "verify" phase) is not executed.

Comment: How do you call Maven?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found the answer myself. Having two definitions of the same plugin (exec-maven-plugin) is only part of the problem: it explains the wrong order of execution but doesn't explain why *cleaner* is never run. The latter problem has the following explanation: maven-cucumber-reporting plugin has code which prevents execution of all further phases of the Maven lifecycle if the build has failed previously. Fortunately, this code can be disabled in parameters - see [this issue at GitHub](https://github.com/damianszczepanik/maven-cucumber-reporting/issues/45) for details.

Comment: You can have two executions of the same plugin in different phases...It depends how you have called Maven?